# Square Root of a matrix: transpose or inverse of eigen vectors?

Tags: inverse, matlab, transpose

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix) is described that the square root of a matrix is defined as

`K^1/2 = V*D^1/2*V^-1`

At the end of scetion 4 of [this](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6072216&tag=1) paper we can see W = K^-1/2es

In the [matlab code](http://people.bu.edu/bkulis/klsh/klsh.htm) in createHashTable.m at line 24 we have:

```
K_half = V_K*diag(d_k)* V_K';
```

As you can see the last term is `V_K'` and not `V_K^-1`. Why?

Comment: If V is ortho-normal the inverse is the transpose.

Comment: That was the trick, didn't notice that `K` was symmetric! If you'll post it as answer I'll chose it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If K is symmetric then there exists an ortho-normal basis, and $V^{-1} = V^T$